# Cannot find Diigo "Send to blog" button

Tags: blog, diigo

I'm looking at this [Diigo site](https://secure.diigo.com/blog_this/config) and would love to use the button but I cannot find the buttons they mention:

[image: Quote: "Send to Blog" can be accessed on the toolbar.]

Do you have the same situation like me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go to your library and turn on `Advance mode`

[image]

Then, select the `resource(s)` that you will use in your new post and select "Publish to blog"

[image]